# Difference of analytic functions...

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are analytic on the open disk in the complex plane.
Suppose $f+\overline g$ is real for all $z$ in the disk. 
Show that $f-g$ is constant.

I would like to show that the difference of x-derivatives, y-derivatives, and combinations of such of $f-g$ are all $0$. I have succeeded for the difference of x-derivatives and y-derivatives without using analyticity. I suspect that I need to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to do the other 2, but all attempts have been unsuccessful. Any help?

Comment: Just notice that $f-g$ is real and use the open mapping theorem or something else like that. The CR equations are fine too. Just apply them to $f-g$ rather than to $f$ and $g$ separately (with $v=0$)

Comment: If $f-g$ doesn't take some non-real values it is constant. Assume it doesn't take some non-real values, then $(f+\bar{g})-(f-g)=\bar{g}+g$ takes some non-real values.

Comment: @fedja I'm just not seeing how to correctly apply and manipulate the CR equations here.

Comment: $f-g=u+iv$, $v=0$, ergo $u_x=\dots, u_y=\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f+\overline{g}$ is real on some ball $B$. Then $f+\overline{g} = \overline{f+\overline{g}} = \overline{f}+g$ on $B$. It follows that $f-g = \overline{f-g}$ on $B$. Since $f-g$ is analytic and takes only real values on $B$, it must be constant.

To see that $\phi = f-g$ must be constant (if $\phi$ takes only real values on $B$), you can use the Cauchy Riemann equations, or more directly, note that since $\phi'(z) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{{\phi}(z+\delta)-{\phi}(z)}{{\delta}}$, if $\delta \to 0$ taking purely real values, then $\phi'(z)$ must be real, and if $\delta \to 0$ taking purely imaginary values, then $\phi'(z)$ must be imaginary. Since $\phi'(z)$ is real and imaginary, it must be zero. Hence $\phi$ is constant (since $B$ is connected).